# "An X or a Y" vs. "An X or Y"

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

> You can create a web site or an application with your bare hands.

or

> You can create a web site or application with your bare hands.

?

Also, same for the definite article?

Comment: My gut feeling is the first version is better, though the second may also be correct. And the reason for that is you can have a noun in plural form with a noun in singular form together like this:

`You can take an apple or two pears.` or
`You can take an apple or pears.`

Comment: [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20conjunction%20reduction) will normally delete repeated material in precisely parallel phrases. Each word normally is deletable -- or not -- independently. Thus repeated articles (_a/an_ or _the_), quantifiers (_lots of_ or _most_), adjectives, or any other repeated element can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct in this context because one noun starts with a vowel but the other does not. You can only "merge" the two articles when the same article would be used with both nouns. For example:

> create a website or blog

This works because you can write

> create a website or create a blog

and it would be wordy but correct. However,

> You can create a web site or application with your bare hands.

is wrong because

> You can create a web site or you can create a application with your bare hands

is wrong because you must use `an` with application.

Comment: What is your source for this? I'm a middle-aged native speaker and have never heard of such a rule.

Comment: @equin0x80 this is a rephrasing of johnlawlers comment on OPs post. "Conjunction reduction" only works when the articles are the same; but here, it would be a and an, not "a a" or "an an". its becuase web does not start with a vowel, but application does, so they need different articles.

Comment: I understand the logic, but I don't believe this is a real rule used in the English language. For example, I'd like to see this rule explained in Fowler's "Modern English Usage", or any real book, not just Internet people.